# Counting elements in a list of lists, and returning the count of each list as a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, count

I want to count the elements of a list of lists and then have the output be a list of the count of each list. This an example of a list I made.

```
ListofLists = [[5, 3, 5, 4], ["a", "b", "c"]]
```

I want to then count the elements of each list and return it as a list as so:

```
CountofLists = [4, 3]
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `map()` and `len()` built-in functions:

```
CountofLists = [*map(len, ListofLists)]
print(CountofLists)
```

Prints:

```
[4, 3]
```

---

Or:

```
CountofLists = [len(sublist) for sublist in ListofLists]
print(CountofLists)
```